# How to suspend/minimize/exit Windows Phone application programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

My Windows Phone 8 application checks network connectivity in `OnNavigatedTo` method. If the application finds out there's no network available, what should my program do?

If it was a desktop application, I would pop up a message box, saying "network is required", and exit the program.

I hear in WP exiting is not recommended; we don't often call Application.Current.Terminate().

Is there a way to suspend the application, return to the "desktop" and when users turned on Wifi, he can run my program and raises OnNavigatedTo again?

I know turning on Wifi automatically by the program or navigating to Setting page would be a good design. But I'm currently curious about suspending/minimizing the application.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no good way to programmatically suspend the app. You could hack it by launching another app, but that wouldn't be a very good user experience.

In your case I'd display a message that the app cannot continue without network access and wait for the network. The app isn't completely dead since the network may connect either on its own or by user action.

Flaky network connections are annoying enough without being compounded by the app exiting and users needing to restart it if they temporarily move in and out of a dead spot.

See [How to detect network changes for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh487166(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: And if you **do** want to navigate to either WiFi or Cellular settings, [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662937(v=vs.105).aspx) lists the URIs to use.